# how to fix the width of two divs which are inside a parent div even when zoomed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page, where I have the following HTML. The div `div.assessment-doc` and `div.assessment-rub-div` which are set with the width 75% and 25% are not overlapping when the browser zoom is at 100%. The Iframe content is dynamically loaded on window load.

```css
.contentDiv {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    min-height: 25em;
}

.sectionDiv {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

div.assessment-doc-div {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 400px;
}

div.assessment-rubric-div {
    overflow-y: visible;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentDiv" id="doc">
  <div id="currentSubmission" class="sectionDiv">
    <div class="assessment-doc" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
    <iframe id="sub15031550Iframe0" name="sub15031550Iframe0" width="1277px" height="983px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="document/2339389/15031550?doc=10882892">IFRAME CONTENT
    </iframe>
    </div> <!-- assessment-doc -->
    <div class="assessment-rub-div">
    </div> <!-- assessment-rub-div -->
  </div> <!-- CurrentSubmission -->
</div> <!-- contentDiv -->
```

The problem is when the user zoom's the page using the browser zoom, the right side border of div `div.assessment-doc` is overlapped by div `div.assessment-rub-div` at 110% zoom. How to handle this situation even at any zoom level?

How is this page working ? I want the same functionality in my page.
 On zoom the left and right div's retain the width.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Comment: Do you have any CSS code associated with this?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen added the CSS rules. Thanks

Comment: I can't think of a good way to solve this x-browser 100%. I'd consider using the following technique on your iframe: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php Also, I don't see a "right side border of div `div.assessment-doc`" but you could use `box-shadow:inset...` instead of a border.